# Load script library in JXA (AppleScript JS)

Tags: javascript-automation

I've created a custom `.scpt` file with some library functions and want to load that library in my other scripts.

I've followed [the official guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/UseScriptLibraries.html) by Apple, and here is what I've got:

### A) Test with AppleScript

**Library File: `~/Library/Script Libraries/Sample Library 1.scpt`**

```
on changeCase(theText)
    set theComparisonCharacters to "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    set theSourceCharacters to "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    set theAlteredText to ""
    
    repeat with aCharacter in theText
        set theOffset to offset of aCharacter in theComparisonCharacters
        if theOffset is not 0 then
            set theAlteredText to (theAlteredText & character theOffset of theSourceCharacters) as string
        else
            set theAlteredText to (theAlteredText & aCharacter) as string
        end if
    end repeat
    return theAlteredText
end changeCase
```

**Test Script**

```
tell script "Sample Library 1"
    changeCase("Hello World")
end tell
```

**Result:** This solution works. But I'd like to use JXA, so I created the second test case below.

### B) Test with JXA

**Library File: `~/Library/Script Libraries/Sample Library 2.scpt`**

```js
function changeCase(text) {
    return text.toUpperCase();
}
```

**Test Script**

```js
var lib = Library("Sample Library 2")
lib.changeCase("Hello World")
```

**Result:** The Script Editor crashes when I run the script. The following error is displayed in the error report

```
Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSXMLDocument initWithData:options:error:]: nil argument'
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What is happening here, and how can I fix that crash when using JXA?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution:

The Library file `~/Library/Script Libraries/Sample Library 2.scpt` needs to be a "Script Bundle" with the extension `.scptd`

Summary:

1. JXA libraries need to be saved as "Script-Bundles" ("Save As ... → Script-Bundle").
2. JXA libraries can only be used by other JXA scripts
3. AppleScript files can never load a JXA library.
4. AppleScript libraries that are "Script" type can be used by other AppleScript files.
5. AppleScript libraries that are "Script-Bundles" can be used by JXA scripts and AppleScript files.

To make it simple, I recommend saving all libraries as a "Script Bundle"

Comment: THANK YOU!  Not sure I would have ever figured that out without your Q&A here.
Wish I could upvote it a lot more!